# Java spring boot configuration properties not loaded EnableConfigurationProperties not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I got values in my spring boot application.properties I am unable to use it in my java class.
 when i do `System.out.println("@@@@ "+onlinePajakProperties.getAuthentication());` data is not shown, null pointer error.

application.properties

```
pajak.authentication = tLFGed7iTD1rztqn9z8aMS0PkCPqBW0i


@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({    
    OnlinePajakProperties.class
})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NextGenAccountingApplication.class, args);
    }

}


import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pajak")
public class OnlinePajakProperties {
    private String  authentication;

    public String getAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}


@Service
public class APISservice {

    String urlPath;

    @Autowired
    private OnlinePajakProperties onlinePajakProperties;

    public void getvalue(){
        if(onlinePajakProperties == null) {
            System.out.println("onlinePajakProperties  is NUll");
        }
        //this line shows no data
        System.out.println("@@@@ "+onlinePajakProperties.getAuthentication());      
    }
}
```

Comment: Any spring component should be able to read it in simply using `@Value("${pajak.authentication}") String myString;`

Answer (score 0):

You should add setter for `authentication` property.

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pajak")
public class OnlinePajakProperties {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String  authentication;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. my 'onlinePajakProperties ' is still null. problem is in APIService   OnlinePajakProperties onlinePajakProperties doesn't get initialised